# Que tipo de informações são permitidas no perfil do usuário?

Tags: debate, perfil

O perfil do usuário possui um campo de edição similar aos das perguntas/respostas, onde se pode inserir não apenas texto, mas imagens e links.

Minha dúvida é se esse campo é moderado, ou seja, se é de livre edição podendo o usuário postar qualquer coisa ou isso também pode ser avaliado pela moderação caso haja algo errado, que vá de contra às regras do site. Até porque não existe nenhum tipo de link para sinalizar algo errado no texto do perfil do usuário (o que não impede de alguém buscar outros meios e denúncia caso haja algo que julgue impróprio).

Mas a dúvida é se o conteúdo que o usuário postar em seu perfil está sujeito à moderação, se ele pode ser repreendido por algo que colocou lá, um link, uma imagem, um texto etc., pode colocar o que quiser ou existe uma orientação do site para isso?

> **Nota:** já li muitas documentações do site e não vi nada falando a respeito disso. Se tiver algo que eu não tenha visto, me perdoem.

Comment: Não sei se haverá algo mais a considerar, mas terá sempre de ter em conta o [Código de Conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: A [Política de Utilização Aceitável](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) da rede diz o que pode ou não. Abrange tanto as postagens quanto qualquer meio de comunicação do site, seja chat, comentários ou o conteúdo do perfil.

Comment: Como não há nada específico, acho que deve ser observado a regra geral, como cita o @bio. É igual a vida civil: quando não há uma legislação específica, adota-se a geral.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Embora pareça não haver uma documentação oficial do que pode ou não ser postado na descrição do perfil nas Redes da Stack Exchange, há uma documentação oficial, a [Política de Utilização Aceitável](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy), que abrange todo site e serviços oferecidos e que certamente inclui as áreas do perfil.

Ela cita os principais pontos dos quais você deve seguir para não violar as regras. Em tradução livre:

> **Uso Ilegal.** O Stack Exchange não pode ser usado para fins ilegais. Exemplos disso incluem o uso do Stack Exchange para fins fraudulentos ou a operação de um site de phishing (usado para obter informações de conta e senha).
>
> **Spam.** Os usuários que não publicam conteúdo significativo, usam meios enganosos para gerar receita ou tráfego, ou cujo objetivo principal é o marketing de afiliados, serão suspensos.
>
> **Roubo de identidade e privacidade.** Os usuários que se apropriam da identidade de outra pessoa não são permitidos. Os usuários não podem postar informações pessoais ou confidenciais de outras pessoas, incluindo, entre outros, números de cartão de crédito, números de seguridade social e números de carteira de motorista e outros. Você não pode postar informações como senhas, nomes de usuário, números de telefone, endereços e endereços de e-mail de outras pessoas, a menos que já estejam acessíveis publicamente na Web.
>
> **Discurso de ódio, difamação e calúnia.** Discurso de ódio e outro conteúdo questionável que seja ilegal, difamatório e fraudulento. Note que uma alegação de expressão difamatória, por si só, não estabelece difamação. A verdade ou falsidade de um pouco de expressão é um elemento-chave no estabelecimento de difamação e não estamos em posição de fazer esse tipo de julgamento baseado em fatos. Dito isso, se tivermos motivos para acreditar que uma declaração em particular é difamatória (uma ordem judicial, por exemplo), removeremos essa declaração.
>
> **Pertubação e exploração.** Nós encerraremos as contas e bloquearemos os endereços daqueles que tentarem o uso não autorizado da Stack Exchange Network.
>
> **Direito autoral.** O uso de material protegido por direitos autorais não constitui violação em todos os casos. Em geral, no entanto, os usuários devem ter cuidado ao usar conteúdo protegido por direitos autorais sem a permissão de quem o criou. É nossa política responder a notificações de supostas infrações enviadas ao legal *(at) stackoverflow (dot) com* que estejam em conformidade com o [Digital Millennium Copyright Act ("DMCA")](http://www.loc.gov/copyright/legislation/dmca.pdf).
>
> **Registro de Massa e Automação.** Contas que são registradas automaticamente ou sistematicamente serão removidas e o acesso será permanentemente suspenso.
>
> **Material Sexualmente Explícito.** As contas que usam o Stack Exchange para publicar material pornográfico ou sexualmente explícito, ou links para ele, serão suspensas.

<sub>Traduzido (quase inteiramente) pelo [Google Tradutor.](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=pt&js=y&prev=_t&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Flegal%2Facceptable-use-policy&edit-text=)</sub>