# Como denunciar o perfil de alguém?

Tags: suporte, sinalização

A pergunta é direta e subjetiva: como eu denunciou ou sinalizo um usuário por alguma coisa inadequada na biografia do perfil, de forma que **minha identidade não seja revelada**?

Eu sei que é possível fazer isso em comentários, perguntas, respostas e no chat. Mas, não achei nenhum lugar na exibição de perfil onde possa relatar alguma inadimplência.

Como sinalizo um perfil e sua biografia?

Comment: Pode sinalizar pela resposta ou comentário do próprio usuário. Quando sinalizado aos moderadores aparece uma caixa de texto, basta descrever porque está sinalizando e que o problema está no perfil.

Comment: Relacionada: [Que tipo de informações são permitidas no perfil do usuário?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7300/5878)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você já revelou sua identidade :P

Sinalize em um comentário da pessoa descrevendo o problema diretamente na última opção, só moderadores podem ver essas sinalizações. Existem outras formas de contactar os moderadores ou a SE sobre isso, mas a sinalização é a mais adequada. Não existe uma sinalização no perfil.

> [image: Screenshot do modal de sinalização, com destaque para a opção que permite descrição textual personalizada]